# How to Make SSIS Package to use 64bit Excel drivers(ACE.OLEDB)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

Very Sorry If the question is already asked. But after a lot of research i'm posting this.

I developed a SSIS package which will import the excel data to SQLSERVER db. The package is working fine if i run the package in my local machine using 32 bit run time. But i got the requirement to run the package in production server with 64 bit runt time. For that i am trying to run the package in 64bit by setting the property **Run 64bit Runtime to TRUE** But it failed with the below error.

FYI, My local machine is having 64 bit OS with 32bit oledb drivers.
     Production Server is having 64 bit OS with 32bit oledb drivers.

However, If i got the both 32bit and 64bit OLEDB drivers installed in my machine. How can i make my SSIS package to use the 64bit drivers but not 32 bit one's.

When i tried to get the 64bit Excel drivers, i found that ***The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet and the Jet ODBC driver are available in 32-bit versions only. We can't run them in 64 bit mode.***

Source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/

ERROR:
**[Excel Source [34]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC00F9304.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.**

Comment: There are two distinct driver technologies mentioned in your question: JET, Joint Engine Technology and ACE, Access Connectivity Engine. JET is used for Excel 2003/97 format (.xls) files while ACE is used for 2007+ format (.xlsx). JET only comes in 32bit flavour. ACE comes in [32 and 64 bits](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) You will then need to select the correct `dtexec` version to match your driver bittedness

Comment: Great answer @billinkc. Your answered cleared half of my confusion.
But if i have .xls file need to processed, in this case can i opt for ACE of 64 bit  or i should go for only JET??? Please be more specific.